# How do I output each Perl array element surrounded in quotes?

Tags: perl, arrays, string

I want to output the elements of an array in a specific format in Perl.

```
@myArray = ("A", "B", "C");
$text = something;
```

Something should be the string '`"A" "B" "C"`' (each element enclosed in double quotes).

However, if `@myArray` is empty, then `$text` should be too.
I thought of using `join()`, such as

```
$text = "\"" . join("\" \"", @myArray) . "\"";
if ($text eq "\"\"")
{
    $text = "";
}
```

Which I think would work. However, is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @a    = qw/ A B C /;
my @b;
my $text = join ' ', map { qq/"$_"/ } @a;
print "text for (@a) is [$text]\n";

$text = join ' ', map { qq/"$_"/ } @b;
print "text for (@b) is [$text]\n";
```

Also, to make the code cleaner, you can use the [`qq//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) operator (behaves exactly like `""`, but you can chose your delimiter) to avoid having escape the `"`s.

Comment: I'm a big fan of map. It's incredibly useful and I think every programmer should learn how to use it.

Comment: map and reduce (from List::Util) are vital higher order functions.  If you like map, you will love Higher Order Perl by Mark Jason Dominus: http://hop.perl.plover.com/

Comment: Is there a way to do this for single quotes?

Comment: @JP. Yes, it is even simpler: `map { "'$_'" } @a`.

Answer (score 5):

Chas. has the right answer, but sometimes I use the `$"` variable, which holds the string to put between array elements for interpolation:

```
my $text = do { local $" = q<" ">; qq<"@array"> };
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about using a "join". Do you want a single scalar string with quoted elements or do you just want an array with quoted elements? If the latter then I suspect the following would do it

```
my @a = qw|a b c|;
@a = map {qq|"$_"|} @a;
```

Of course this sidesteps the test whether the elements were quoted originally. If you want the array elements quoted for inserting into a database using DBI for example, then the more appropriate way could be:

```
@a = map{$dbh->quote($_)} @a;
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Why are you concatenating instead of interpolating?  Good advice on the second bit though, I had assumed this was for output not passing to something else that would interpret the values as strings.

Comment: DOH! Of course. :) Change the second line of my first fragment to: @a = map {qq|"$_"|} @a;

Answer (score -1):

It might not do exactly what you're asking, but I'm a big fan of Data::Dumper for this sort of thing.